# Harmonic minor scale structure in piano package

Tags: tikz-pgf, musixtex

It is needed to print the letter notes in the piano keyboard package, the basic code is as follow:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}

\usepackage{musixtex} 
\usepackage{piano} 
\usepackage{float} %Paquete para posicionar Tablas

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \keyboard[Ao][Bo][Ct][Dt][Et][Ft][Gst][At]
    \caption{Harmonic minor scale structure in A}
    \label{Harmonic}
\end{figure}
  
\end{document}
```

[image: current]

The desired output is as follow:
[image: desired]

Comment: If you want more than seven notes, you can use `xpiano` instead of `piano` and you can do `\keyboard{Ao,Bo,Ct,Dt,Et,Ft,Gst,At}`. But for the decorations in the desired output, you need something else, as shown in the given answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `piano` package is a very very limited package. Here is the complete manual:

> This package adds the \keyboard[1][2]..[7] command to your project.
> When used, it draws a small 2 octaves piano keyboard on your document,
> with up to 7 keys highlighted.
>
> Keys go : Co, Cso, Do, Dso, Eo, Fo, Fso, Go, Gso, Ao, Aso, Bo, Ct,
> Cst, Dt, Dst, Et, Ft, Fst, Gt, Gst, At, Ast and Bt.
>
> Suggested use : \begin{figure}[thpb]\   \centering
> \keyboard[Co][Eo][Gso][Ct][Et]   \caption{C aug chord}
> \label{Chord1} \end{figure}

Notice you can highlight max 7 keys. The empty keyboard can with some difficulty be used in a TikZ picture like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{piano}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
blackkey/.style={
white, scale=0.8,
append after command={\pgfextra{\tikzset{every label/.append style={white, scale=0.8}}}}
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
inner sep=1pt, 
every node/.style={circle, minimum width=14pt, font=\bf},
every label/.style={rectangle, label position=below, label distance=1pt, inner sep=0pt, font=\small}
]
\node[rectangle, anchor=south west, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, shift={(0.03,0.3)}, font=\normalsize, scale=2] {\keyboard};
\node[draw, label={Fun}] at (1,1) {C};
\node[fill=orange, label={[white, scale=0.8]Fun}] at (1.5,2) {};
\node[fill=red] at (2.5,2) {};
\node[fill=orange, label={Fun}] at (2,1) {D};
\node[draw=teal, very thick, fill=orange, label={Fun}] at (3,1) {E};
\node[label={R}] at (6,1) {A};
\node[label={m2}] at (7,1) {B};
\node[label={M3}] at (8,1) {C};
\node[label={p4}] at (9,1) {D};
\node[label={p5}] at (10,1) {E};
\node[label={m6}] at (11,1) {F};
\node[label={R(0)}] at (13,1) {A};
\node[blackkey, label={(m7)}] at (12.5,2.5) {G\#};
\draw[-Stealth]
(6,-0.2)    edge +(0,0.4) -- 
(7,-0.2)    edge +(0,0.4) --
(8,-0.2)    edge +(0,0.4) -- 
(9,-0.2)    edge +(0,0.4) -- 
(10,-0.2)   edge +(0,0.4) -- 
(11,-0.2)   edge +(0,0.4) -- 
(12.4,-0.2) edge +(0,1.4) --
(13,-0.2)   --   +(0,0.4);
\tikzset{every node/.style={font=\normalfont}}
\node at (6.5,-0.5)  {T};
\node at (7.5,-0.5)  {S};
\node at (8.5,-0.5)  {T};
\node at (9.5,-0.5)  {T};
\node at (10.5,-0.5) {S};
\node at (11.8,-0.5) {TS};
\node at (12.7,-0.5) {S};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Keyboard with some highlighted keys and notes]